# Django: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'

Tags: python, django

I have this error, when Im trying to save my form with the data. The form:

```
class EntityCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, chain, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EntityCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['chain'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Chain.objects.filter(pk__in = chain))

    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = '__all__'
```

View:

```
def entity_create(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntityCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():            
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('organisation:entity-list'))
    else:
        chain = request.session['chain']
        form = EntityCreateForm(chain)
    return render (request, 'organisation/entity_form.html', {'form':form})
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Where are you using that form?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update the description, to show the full error traceback (in a new code block).

Comment: Sorry. What do you mean? In the template with {% csrf_token %}.

Comment: @VitAmin, when the error occurs there will be (somewhere) a multiple-line [exception traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) showing the call stack at the time the exception was raised. That contains important information about the cause of the error; please find it and include it in the question description.

Comment: @bignose updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added an unexpected parameter to the `__init__` function of your form. If you're not using this form in a non-standard way, then this parameter will be filled in with `POST` data by Django. To fix that error, you must either overwrite a section of generic view that you're using to include that extra data or pass it in another way.

Comment: The problem was here:

form = EntityCreateForm(request.POST)
=>
form = EntityCreateForm(chain,request.POST)